# A C# datastructure to hold a KeyValue pair with different identifiers than "key" and "value"

Tags: c#, rest, data-structures

I have a list of books and prices saved in a `List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>`, I want to send this List in a REST Call, I convert it to a `JObject`, then send it as the body of my call. It arrives to the REST interface looking something like this:

```
{"key":BookSample1,"value":"17.99"},
{"key":BookSample2,"value":"21.99"},
{"key":BookSample3,"value":"45.49"}
```

My problem is that the interface is expecting something like this:

```
{"Title":BookSample1,"newPrice":"17.99"},
{"Title":BookSample2,"newPrice":"21.99"},
{"Title":BookSample3,"newPrice":"45.49"}
```

I know that the `key` and `value` are readOnly. Is there any way that I can edit the list this way or a different data structure that would let me do that

Comment: How did you serialize a List? You can try to create own converter fro that

Comment: Why not create a custom class with `Title` and `NewPrice` properties and use that instead of `KeyValuePair`, or alternatively in C# 7  you can use value tuples `List<(string Title, double NewPrice)>`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I use JObject.Parse(object);

Comment: `JObject.Parse` is to parse a source json into `JObject`, you are asking about the serilaization, which is opposite. How is `List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>` created and serialized into json?

Comment: So fast to delete question: 
There is no "format" in SOAP Datetime, The type is defined by `xs:dateTime`:

You might be talking about the `DateTime.Kind ` that result in the following serialisation

   <myDate>2020-05-27T08:00:00+02:00</myDate>  Local
   <myDate>2020-05-27T06:00:00Z</myDate>   UTC
   <myDate>2020-05-27T06:00:00</myDate>       Unspecified

Comment: You can do that either using  constructors with a `DateTimeKind` parameter:

```C#
new DateTime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
```

or Using the  [DateTime.ToUniversalTime Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.touniversaltime?view=netcore-3.1)  
and [DateTime.ToLocalTime Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolocaltime?view=netcore-3.1)
for UTC and Local respectivly

Answer (score 4):

Convert the original list of KeyValuePairs to a new list of anonymous objects:

```
theList.Select(kvp => new { Title = kvp.Key, NewPrice = kvp.Value }).ToList();
```

Serializing this object will give you the proper variable names.